# MySQL prepared statements and case sensitivity

Tags: php, mysql, sql, case-insensitive

in the past I used the `query` method of the mysqli class. Now I am rewriting a lot of code using the prepare method.
I have a table with the collation `utf8mb4_bin` (case sensitive) but the user should perform case insensitive query, the past query is this

```sql
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM utenti WHERE nome LIKE _utf8mb4 ? COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ORDER BY id_utente ASC
```

I know I can not use this syntax with prepared statements, whats is the best way? I thought forcing stored value and query value to lowercase, but I think is not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to apply a case-insensitive collation to the column, and then compare that to your parameter:

```
SELECT * FROM utenti 
WHERE nome COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci LIKE ? 
ORDER BY id_utente ASC
```

P.S.: I recommend to remove `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. It has no purpose if you don't use `LIMIT`. It can only make the performance suck.

Comment: About your *"It an only makes the performance suck"* there Bill. Did you not mean "It can only make the performance suck" or "It only makes the performance suck"? Kind of reads funny.

Comment: You're quite welcome Bill. I was going to edit it myself, but that could have read either way (I stated) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is convert your value to uppercase in php and wrap your column with `upper` in the query.

```
select * from table where upper(column) like ?
```

With the ? being set to the uppercase value of the string you're looking for.